# iPhone mobile homepage: Photo upload as regular file upload

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

Something new for me: How can I get a file-upload on my mobile webpage for iphone, to upload a picture (as profile-thumbnail for example)?

Mabye there is any framework or library which can do this?

Thx for help ;)

Comment: @Aurum Aquila, no sorry, I know some people too, and it's not thaaaaaat important ;) @phix23 why do you mean that? Did Apple provide some features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no interface for uploading content in Mobile Safari. The best workaround I've seen is to have people email files to an address, and then you have some cron jobs that extract uploads from the email.

I saw this recently on the site [My Slow Low](http://myslowlow.com/). One of the guys who built it did a write-up on [extracting IMAP email attachments using php](http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/extracting-attachments-from-emails-with-php/), which could be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out

http://picupapp.com/

Picup is a native iPhone Application that facilitates photo uploads to the web. Since file-upload form fields don't work in Mobile Safari, a webapp can instruct Picup to choose and upload a photo. Once the upload is complete, Picup returns control to the webapp with information about the upload.